# iOS - How do I perform two transitions sequentially?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage, uiviewanimation

I have taken some code from other SO questions, but I must be doing something wonky. The app jumps from the first view to the third. What I'm trying to achieve is:

ViewController 1 Image 1 - loads with an image. Quickly cross-disolves into ViewController 1 image 2.

ViewController 1 Image 2 - flips to ViewController 2.

The cross-disolve happens but takes me to VC2. I've battered at this for most of the day. It's time to ask for help while I go sit in a bathtub.

Here's what I've been doing:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad

        {
            NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
            [super viewDidLoad];
        }

        - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
            NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

            sleep (2);
            [self transition1]; //showing image 1
        }

        - (void) transition1 {
            NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
            /*
            [UIView transitionFromView:firstView
                          toView:secondView
                        duration:3.0
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            [firstView removeFromSuperview];
                        }];
             */

            //this transition doesn't happen

UIImage * secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.firstView
                        duration:5.0f
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:^{
                            self.imageView.image = secondImage;
                        } completion:NULL];



            sleep (2);
            [self transition2];
        }

        - (void) transition2 {
            NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
            self.patterns = [[PatternViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PatternView_iPad" bundle:nil];
            self.patterns.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentViewController:patterns animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE

I've updated my code per Moxy's suggestions as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [self performSelector:@selector(transition1)
             withObject:nil
             afterDelay:2.0f];
}

-(void)transition1
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    UIImage * secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.firstView
                duration:5.0f
                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                            self.imageView.image = secondImage;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            [self performSelector:@selector(transition2)
                                       withObject:nil
                                       afterDelay:2.0f];
                }];
}

-(void)transition2
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    self.patterns = [[PatternViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PatternView_iPad"
                                          bundle:nil];
    self.patterns.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:patterns
                 animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to start your second animation in the first animation's completion block.
Sleep() is something you probably shouldn't be using.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [self performSelector:@selector(transition1)
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:2.0f]
}

-(void)transition1
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    UIImage * secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.firstView
                      duration:5.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                            self.imageView.image = secondImage;
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            [self performSelector:@selector(transition2)
                                       withObject:nil
                                       afterDelay:2.0f]
                     }];
}

-(void)transition2
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    self.patterns = [[PatternViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PatternView_iPad" 
                                                            bundle:nil];
    self.patterns.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:patterns
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Moxy, thanks for that. I get a blank screen for a second, then the cross-disolve to the Pattern VC. I'm sure the images are there.

Comment: Do you set the first image somewhere?

Comment: oh man, that was it!!! Thank you so much. It must have gotten lost in my hacking..

Comment: I have a follow on question. Is it possible to use the crossDissolve transition when moving between ViewControllers? i.e. can I do the same as 1 above for transition2? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, just use UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve as a modalTransitionStyle

Comment: I swear I tried that.. Thanks again Now it works - (last question - promise).. Is there a way to change the duration on that second transition?

Comment: Not by using -presentViewController:animated:completion: . You could use a custom segue, or fake it by making an animation that looks like what you need and then present the modal view controller without animation (It depends a lot on the case)

Comment: ok. understood. just wanted to know I wasn't missing something else.